# Why can not debug in IDE when using Spring Boot 1.4.1 or 1.4.2

Tags: spring, debugging, intellij-idea, ide

IDE can not suspend on breakpoints after upgrade to Spring Boot 1.4.1 or 1.4.2

Comment: how do you invoke the debugger

Comment: I upgraded from 1.4.0 to 1.4.2 and i can